# Auto convert str to Path in function arguments

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I'm writing a function that needs a filename as input parameter. I now want to support passing both str and Path arguments, but later assume everything is of type Path. I can now implement everything like

```py
from pathlib import Path
def func(filename: Path|str):
  filename = Path(filename)
  ...

func("file.ext")
```

Is this the recommended way of doing this or can I somehow make python implicitly convert str arguments to Path upon calling, like in c++

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
void func(std::filesystem::path file) {
  ...
}
func("file.ext");
```

My code works, I just want to know if it could be better / more pythonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're doing is close enough! If you have this setup multiple times you might wanna give the type a name (e.g. `AnyPath = str | Path` or something). If you wanna go fancy, you might wanna check out `os.PathLike`.

## The longer answer

I want to do the same thing, that's how I ended up here and tried to look up how they do it elsewhere. This my short answer above comes from the this quick "exploration".

### The `open()` builtin

In `buildins.pyi`, the file which describes the types of the python built-in commands such as `open()`, it says:

```py
_OpenFile = Union[AnyPath, int]
# ... snip ...
def open(
    file: _OpenFile,
    # ... snip ...
```

and if you look up `AnyPath` it is defined as

```py
if sys.version_info >= (3, 6):
    from os import PathLike

    # ... snip ...
    AnyPath = Union[str, bytes, PathLike[str], PathLike[bytes]]
else:
    # ... snip ...
```

`PathLike` comes from `os` (not from `pathlib`) and is defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/618d7256e78da8200f6e2c6235094a1ef885dca4/Lib/os.py#L1086).

### In `numpy.load()`

Numpy does something similar:

```py
def load(
    file: str | bytes | os.PathLike[Any] | _SupportsReadSeek[bytes],
    # ... snip ...
```